# Listview does not populate on newer android versions

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform, picasso

I am creating a listview which loads items from parse.com into a custom adapter. The app works fine on devices of api below 19. It however crashes with absolutely no error on the logcat in api 19 and above. I have been stuck on this issue for two days now. Here is my code:

```
package com.edwardokoth.turnapp.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.edwardokoth.turnapp.R;
import com.edwardokoth.turnapp.adapters.HomepageAdapter;
import com.edwardokoth.turnapp.utils.Helper;
import com.edwardokoth.turnapp.utils.ParseConstants;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseImageView;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;

import java.util.List;

public class WhatsHotFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {
    public static String[] objectIds;
    public static ParseFile[] images;
    private Callbacks activity;
    private ProgressBar  whatsHotProgressBar;
    protected SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    int initialLimit = 10, newLimit = initialLimit, mListviewCount;
    private boolean hasFooterButton;

    public WhatsHotFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot,
                container, false); // sets the xml to be used in this fragment.


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        whatsHotProgressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.whatsHotProgressBar);
        whatsHotProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    public interface Callbacks {
        void onItemSelected(ParseFile image, String objectId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ParseFile image = images[position];
        String objectId = objectIds[position];
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        activity.onItemSelected(image, objectId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = (Callbacks) activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(Helper.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
            retrieveEventList(newLimit);
        }else {
            Helper.makeToast(getActivity(), "Network is unavailable");
        }

        Button btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());
        btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");



        if(!hasFooterButton) {
            getListView().addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
            hasFooterButton = true;

            btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(Helper.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                                getActivity());
                        whatsHotProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        newLimit += 4;
                        mListviewCount = getListView().getCount() - 3;
                        retrieveEventList(newLimit);
                    }else {
                        Helper.makeToast(getActivity(), "Network is unavailable");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }


    protected SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener mOnRefreshListener = new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            retrieveEventList(initialLimit);
        }
    };


    private void retrieveEventList(int limit) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> myQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
        myQuery.addDescendingOrder("rsvp");
        myQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
        myQuery.setLimit(limit);
        myQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> eventObjects, ParseException e) {
                whatsHotProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
                if (e == null) {
                    String[] eventNames = new String[eventObjects.size()];
                    images = new ParseFile[eventObjects.size()];
                    objectIds = new String[eventObjects.size()];

                    int i = 0;
                    for (ParseObject user : eventObjects) {
                        eventNames[i] = eventObjects.get(i).getString("eventName");
                        images[i] = user.getParseFile("bannerImage");
                        objectIds[i] = user.getObjectId();
                        i++;
                    }
                    HomepageAdapter homepageAdapter = new HomepageAdapter(getActivity(),
                            R.layout.party_fragment, eventNames, images);
                    setListAdapter(homepageAdapter);
//                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test));
                    if(getListView().getAdapter() == null) {

                    }else {
//                        getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(mListviewCount);
                        getListView().setSelection(mListviewCount);
                    }

                    if(eventObjects.isEmpty()){
                        Helper.showEmptyTextView("No items to display", getListView());
                    }
                } else {
                    Helper.showEmptyTextView("No items to display", getListView());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the adapter class. As you can see from the comments, the app crashes whithin this class

```
package com.edwardokoth.turnapp.adapters;



import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.edwardokoth.turnapp.R;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by Arnold on 8/27/2015.
 */
public class HomepageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    protected Context context;
    String[] strings;
    ParseFile[] images;
    Uri fileUri;



    public HomepageAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects,
                     ParseFile[] images) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.strings = objects;
        this.images = images;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return strings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.party_fragment, parent, false);

        ParseImageView iv = (ParseImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.eventPic); //After lots of debugging, I found out that the app crashes around this point   
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.event_name_tv_home);

        tv.setText(strings[position]);


        fileUri = Uri.parse(images[position].getUrl());

        Picasso.with(context).load(fileUri).fit().into(iv);


        return row;
    }
}
```

This is the xml file containing the listview:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_events_at_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/whatsHotProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="false" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the file being used for the customizing the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_and_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            >

            <com.parse.ParseImageView
                android:id="@+id/eventPic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_child"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_name_tv_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ravin&apos; pool party"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:shadowColor="#000"
                android:shadowDx="10"
                android:shadowRadius="30"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/eventPic"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 'It however crashes with absolutely no error on the logcat' - this is not possible, there should be a stacktrace if your app crashes.

Comment: @agamov I think it's a stupid bug in Android Studio (at least for me) that logcat doesn't show any of the errors, even if the app crashes. It could be an ACRA bug though since i'm using that as well to upload the crash logs. I've resorted to checking the exception trace in the output that ACRA uploads. As for the question, `ListView` should work on all versions. Try to figure out where it crashes by putting breakpoints if you can't get the kogcat output.

Comment: I have done alot of debugging and I found out the app crashes on the Adapter class somewhere after : View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.party_fragment, parent, false);

Comment: Any special reason you are not using ParseQueryAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new improved version/ kindof ListView . Its the RecyclerView.
Try out using RecyclerView. If you are new to this widget, please read enough and before putting hands on your code. [Example](http://simplestandroidtutorial.blogspot.in/)

Comment: I've followed the tutorial and added a recycler view. Exactly the same result! Works like a charm on devices and emulators below api 19 but crashes without giving reason on api 19 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing following lines from `RelativeLayout` in your item layout.

```
android:layout_weight="25"
android:weightSum="100"
android:elevation="20dp"
```

Attribute `android:elevation` was added in API21. That might be causing the problem. And the first two attributes looks like unnecessary.

If you want to elevate a `View` you should use `CardView` as container. And make sure to read carefully [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) documentation because it doesn't behave consistently on all platforms.

And check out [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) for `ListView`s. This will improve performances if you have a large list.

Comment: I've changed the code to use the ViewHolder and after hundreds of log statements I've realized that the position variable in getView() is being recycled in newer versions while it simply increments in older versions. eg. if the no of items is six, in older versions the position variable goes 0,1,2,3,4,5 while in newer versions it is recycled to 0,1,2,3,0,1. Is there any way to workaround this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are not caching the position variable in your ViewHolder?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! It's kind of strange but the whole problem was fixed simply by changing the shadow radius on my textview from 30 to 20.Thanks for all the help.